# What happened to IHtmlContent?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm getting ready to update a library to work with ASP.NET Core 3.0. My library provides an implementation of [`IHtmlContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.html.ihtmlcontent?view=aspnetcore-2.2), which used to live in [the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions/).

That package seems not to have been updated with the release of .NET Core 3.0 — it's still at version 2.2.0 and hasn't been updated in nearly a year. I can't find any documentation for `IHtmlContent` in the .NET API Browser for version 3.0 either (either by switching the dropdown from the above link to "ASP.NET Core 3.0" or by searching for it).

Where did `IHtmlContent` move to? Am I meant to continue using the one from the `Abstractions` package? Where are the docs?

Comment: It's no longer maintained as a package - it's available via a [Framework Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#framework-reference).

Comment: Where are the docs?

Comment: The WinForms code has not had an update in literal *decades*, as it was deprecated. Now with it being re-introduced with .NET Core? We might see some movement here.